# Objective-C type downcasting

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am trying to override

```
- (void)makeWindowControllers;
```

Here is the code for it:

```
NSStoryboard* const storyboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
NSWindowController* const windowController = [storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"Document Window Controller"];
```

And then I would like to add an image to `ViewController` that user has selected through `open...` in Swift I would simply do:

```
(windowController.contentViewController as? ViewController)?.imageView?.image = openedImage
```

How I could do this downcasting in Objective-C? I really got confused since I haven't done much type converting while I was learning C. Thanks.

Comment: `[[((ViewController *)[windowController contentViewController]) imageView] setImage: openedImage];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[((ViewController *)[windowController contentViewController]) imageView] setImage: openedImage];
```